# Map array numeric values to a specific interval in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I want to map numeric elements of a multidimensional array to a specific interval, i will show a example:

Original array:

```
arr = [[-30,2,-1],[0,3,-20],[1,20,7],[40,60,50]]
```

I want to map values of array `arr` to a interval between 0 and 255

Resultant array:

```
arr_result = [[0, 18, 10], [5, 20, 2], [200, 255, 220]]
```

My minimum value of the original array `arr[0][0] = -30` now is `0` and my max value `arr[3][1] = 60` now is `255` and then the other values are switched to numbers between my minimum and maximum values `0 and 255`

Any tips?

Comment: Huh?  What do you mean map them to the interval?  Do you mean scale them?  (e.g. -30 => 0, 60 => 255)?

Comment: Some example of the expected result would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about my initial explanation, I've added a example and expect now this looks more clear. Maerics its just what you understood

Comment: are you sure those values in `arr_result` are correct?

Comment: The other values are randomly created between you min and max?

Comment: Tokland my values in the arr_result are incorrect, but its only for demonstration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
xss = [[-30, 2, -1], [0, 3, -20], [1, 20, 7], [40, 60, 50]]
min, max = xss.flatten(1).minmax
factor = 255.0 / (max - min)
yss = xss.map { |xs| xs.map { |x| (factor * (x - min)).round } }
#=> => [[0, 91, 82], [85, 94, 28], [88, 142, 105], [198, 255, 227]]
```